# MySQL command line color prompt

Tags: mysql, colors, prompt

I want to add colors to the MySQL command line color prompt.

I have so far in a script (database.sh):

```
mysql -uroot -hlocalhost -A --prompt="\u@\h:\d> "
```

I would like `root` to be **red**, `@` to be **blue**, `localhost` to be **green** and `database` to be **cyan**:

```
root@localhost:database>
```

Is it possible to do this in my script?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1940324/mysql-color-scheme

Comment: I saw it but it does not work

Comment: Yeah I think it's possible the same way a in your regular shell prompt. Your best bet is probably [some wrapper](http://www.caliban.org/ruby/acoc.shtml) or a more advanced MySQL-client.

Comment: Does your setup support ANSI escape codes? If it does then you can use them in the following way: --prompt=" ^[[1;33mDTHIS PART IS IN YELLOW COLOUR^[[0m \u@\h:\d> "

Answer (score 14):

Don't listen to people who say you can't.  Here:

```
$ alias colormysql=$(echo -e 'mysql --prompt="\x1B[31m\\u\x1B[34m@\x1B[32m\\h\x1B[0m:\x1B[36m\\d>\x1B[0m "')
```

Then:

```
$ colormysql -hHOSTNAME -uUSERNAME -pPASSWORD ...
```

Comment: Can you give some more explanation as to why this works, but you can't just pass ANSI codes?

Comment: ```$(foo)``` executes the result of foo, in this case echo's output.  The -e to echo expands the \x1b into an escape char.  The \x1b[31m is a terminal control code that sets the current color to red.  And so forth.  \x1b[0m returns the color to the default terminal color.

Comment: Looks nice, but when using home/end, the cursour end of at the wrong position :-(

Comment: when testing colors, i recomendate you skip the alias step, for exemple by doing: ``mysql --prompt="`echo -e '\033[01;32m\\d\033[01;34m >\033[00m '`"``

Comment: Also adding escape codes enclosing the color codes make this work properly (navigating the history will work without make your prompt a mess) like this: $ alias colormysql=$(echo -e 'mysql --prompt="\001\x1B[31m\002\\u\001\x1B[34m\002@\001\x1B[32m\002\\h\001\x1B[0m\002:\001\x1B[36m\002\\d>\001\x1B[0m\002 "')

Comment: @dossy It doesn't work as expected. You have to embed each terminal sequence characters in `\[` and `\]`, like so: `\[\x1B[31m\]` - if you don't, `readline` will be confused about the string's length and won't support carriage return correctly (try to write multiple lines, then press and hold backspace). I don't know, however, how to escape it correctly in alias. Do you?

Comment: @CyprianGuerra - Look at @david-santamaria's comment above, using `\001` and `\002` around the sequences for proper `readline` support.

    `$ alias colormysql=$(echo -e 'mysql --prompt="\001\x1B[31m\002\\u\001\x1B[34m\002@\001\x1B[32m\002\\h\001\x1B[0m\002:\001\x1B[36m\002\\d>\001\x1B[0m\002 "')`

There appears to be some kind of rendering issue with copy-and-pasting that from the browser, where the `\002:\001` portion of the command is being put into the clipboard as `\002:\<200c><200b>001` (where `<200c>` and `<200b>` are non-printing characters, probably the CR/NL from word-wrapping).

Comment: Thanks! I read this comment and tried to copy&paste but missed the non-printables and just assumed it doesn't work like the rest of the suggestions I tried over the week. But this one really does. *surprised*

Answer (score 8):

### Walkthrough on setting up colorized mysql prompt.

**Step 1.  Understand how to login normally with a set prompt:**

```
eric@dev ~ $ mysql --host=yourhost.com -u username --prompt="foobar> " -p
Enter password:
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 711
Server version: 5.6.19 MySQL Community Server (GPL)

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

foobar>
```

**Step 2.  Understand how you can pipe an interpreted expression through echo to 'alias':**

Which does exactly the same as step 1 above:

```
eric@dev ~ $ alias penguins=$(echo -e 'mysql --host=yourhost.com -u dev --prompt="foobar> " -p')
eric@dev ~ $ penguins
Enter password:
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 713
Server version: 5.6.19 MySQL Community Server (GPL)

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

foobar> exit
Bye
eric@dev ~ $
```

**Step 3.  Understand how echo -e evaluates the colorized expression:**

This colors the "foobar>" prompt red:

```
alias penguins=$(echo -e 'mysql --host=yourhost.com -u dev --prompt="\x1B[31mfoobar>\x1B[0m " -p')
penguins
```

Like this:

[image]

**Step 4.  If you are confused as to what is going on here:**

Look at the expression: `\x1B[31mfoobar>\x1B[0m`

It has three parts:

```
code               what it means:

\x1B[31m           Start colorizing, 31m is red.
foobar>            prompt text
\x1B[0m            Stop colorizing.
```

**Step 4.  Advanced, Lets make the prompt real nice:**

```
eric@dev ~ $ alias penguins=$(echo -e 'mysql --host=yourhost.com -u dev --prompt="\x1B[31m\\u\x1B[34m@\x1B[32m\\v\x1B[0m:\x1B[36m\\d>\x1B[0m " -p')
eric@dev ~ $ penguins
```

[image]

If you are confused as to what this massive code does:

```
\x1B[31m\\u\x1B[34m@\x1B[32m\\v\x1B[0m:\x1B[36m\\d>\x1B[0m
```

Explanation:

```
Code         Note
\x1B[31m     Start colorizing red
\\u          escape the backslash for passage through echo, and print username
\x1B[34m     Start colorizing dark blue
@            literal at sign
\x1B[32m     Start colorizing green
\\v          escape the backslash for passage through echo, print server version
\x1B[0m      Stop colorizing
:            literal colon
\x1B[36m     Start colorizing cyan
\\d>         Backslash for passage through echo, print default db and >
\x1B[0m      Stop colorizing.
```

So wow.  Much codes.

Comment: Any idea on how to escape terminal codes correctly so that `readline` wouldn't be confused about the line length and editing multiple lines in `mysql` command line would be possible? (try to write multiple lines, then press and hold backspace)

Comment: This is a completely separate tangent question that should be asked as a separate stackoverflow question.  Of course it's possible with access to a turing complete programming language, but the question is how, I don't know without putting a few hours into it.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted the prompt to be in the title of my terminals, which is essentially the same problem as wanting a colored prompt, just a different escape code. Came across this and wondered if I could do it without having to remember a special alias like the `colormysql` etc mentioned in the answers.

I've added the following to my `.bashrc` which does the trick on my machine:

`export MYSQL_PS1=$(echo -e "\033]0;\u@\h [\d]\007\u@\h [\d]> ")`

what this does is use `echo -e` to generate the raw escape characters (rather than the symbolic ones) to the `MYSQL_PS1` variable. This should also work with colors.

Answer (score 0):

Just right-click on the title bar, select defaults you will get access to do everything in terms of color, font & background. Restart the command line to see the changes.

Answer (score -2):

It's a quite unfortunate answer, but you cannot.

Regarding the use of ANSI escape sequences, MySQL only allows the [following](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/option-files.html):

> You can use the escape sequences “\b”, “\t”, “\n”, “\r”, “\”, and “\s” in option values to represent the backspace, tab, newline, carriage return, backslash, and space characters.

Regarding cmjdmiller's answer, **grc** only works to display output from MySQL's shell through a "pager".

The best you could do is use **rlwrap** like this:
`rlwrap -a -p'GREEN' mysql -uroot -hlocalhost -A --prompt="\u@\h:\d> "`. This will not give you fine-grained control however as it colorizes the entire prompt. Also be careful because it displays the password in cleartext.

Comment: This is out of date.  There are a host of possible values for the prompt option.  See here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql-commands.html

Comment: **result for me** [on stack-over-flow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1940324/mysql-color-scheme/46731453#46731453)

Comment: It's not so much out of date as just wrong.  for one thing, [ANSI escape sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) are something entirely independent of MySQL, and for another, they can certainly be used, as amply demonstrated in the other answers here.