# mysql 5.7.27 command line prompt shows un-escaped characters

Tags: command-line, mysql, prompt

I'm using mysql 5.7.27 in CentOS 7, and I want a colorful prompt in command line. I found a solution [here](https://superuser.com/questions/397183/mysql-command-line-color-prompt). But it doesn't work for my environment.

```
alias penguins=$(echo -e 'mysql --prompt="\x1B[31m\\u\x1B[34m@\x1B[32m\\v\x1B[0m:\x1B[36m\\d>\x1B[0m " ')
```

Here is the [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PstoG.png)

I searched for the all day but didn't find any solution, even `rlwrap` doesn't work for my mysql prompt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a workaround eventually.

readline has been replaced by editline wrapper since [mysql 5.6.5](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/source-configuration-options.html#option_cmake_with_readline), that's why `rlwrap` and other solutions don't work for me.

So I used and older client version - 5.6.4 - to connect to mysql server.